# Uploading image to server and reading the response

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have posted an image file to the server which is having a php file.

I used the following code :

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {

        byte[] sbytedata = ReadToEnd(e.ChosenPhoto);
        string s = sbytedata.ToString();
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Uri u = new Uri("http://example.com/file.php");
        wc.OpenWriteCompleted+=new OpenWriteCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenWriteCompleted);
        wc.OpenWriteAsync(u, "POST", sbytedata);

    }
}

public static void wc_OpenWriteCompleted(object sender, OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        object[] objArr = e.UserState as object[];
        byte[] fileContent = e.UserState as byte[];

        Stream outputStream = e.Result;
        outputStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
        outputStream.Flush();
        outputStream.Close();
        string s = e.Result.ToString(); 

    }
}
```

But how to read the response from the server which returns the image file and how to display that image ?

Comment: What data (if any) is coming back?

Comment: It will return the image with some effects applied to it.i want to read that image and display it

Comment: If the byte stream is being returned, `BitmapImage` can use that data to create the source for an `Image` which can be displayed.

Comment: I have thought of this code.is this the right way?                                                                   wc.OpenReadCompleted += OnOpenReadCompleted;


private void OnOpenReadCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

     System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmpimg = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bmpimg.SetSource(e.Result);
            image1.Source = bmpimg;
    
    }

Comment: that looks right, you then add that to the page (ie. XAML file) and it should display?